# Linux need for environment variables

Tags: environment-variables

I have been reading about environment variables in Linux. I can understand how to set / read them.

What I want to ask is conceptually why were environment variables added to Linux ? Is there a system requirement that cannot be fulfilled without them ?

To my mind, it seems like an additional configuration layer was needed for some reason, something that was decoupled from the actual process functionality. I want to know the opinion of more experienced developers.

Comment: Global state, it's quick and dirty, but useful. Anyway, you need to deal with global state at some level and I guess the shell is the most appropriate place. (and of course, it's not really global, it is global to a shell invocation as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

environment variables [herein: *env*] fulfill a need that can't [conveniently] be handled in other ways.

So, we ask the question:  *How do programs get configuration data that may change on each invocation?*

---

We *could* pass everything as program arguments: `pgmA PATH=... DISPLAY=...` but the program would have to parse that.  And, when pgmA invokes pgmB, it would have to pass this data along as arguments.  In other words, *every* program would have to be aware of *every* variable, even if it had no use for the variable itself.

We *could* put everything in a config file, but we'd need a different one for each invocation.  Where to put these files, how to guarantee they have unique names, how/when to delete them when they're no longer needed [even in the face of an aborted program], becomes intractable.

---

With env variables, they reside in the program in a special memory section that the kernel creates when the program is execed, and the std `execvp` et. al. (with some kernel help) will cheerfully pass along this environment without most programs having to do anything.

However, pgmA is at liberty, after a `fork`, and in the child before `execvp` to change something for pgmB (e.g. adds an extra directory to `PATH`).  In other words, env is hierarchical between parent and child (e.g. changing child does *not* change parent--a good thing)

The env also allows things to be passed around that lower order programs need.  Consider that pgmA `fork/exec`s pgmB which in turn `fork/exec`s pgmC.  pgmA/pgmB are just ordinary programs [and don't use *any* env variables themselves].  But pgmC is `xterm` which needs to know what X11 display to output on.  It gets that from the `DISPLAY` env var.

Consider that we ran the above from the main GUI console from within a window terminal program.  `DISPLAY` would [probably] be `:0`.  The `xterm` shows up on the local screen. Now consider that we do the same exact thing from an ssh login.  Here `DISPLAY` will be `w.x.y.z:0` and the `xterm` will execute on the local machine, but will display itself on the remote system's screen.

---

Another major use of the environment is to provide configuration for things that don't have [legitimate] access to `argv` or config files.  Namely, shared libraries [`.so`s].  Here are two examples:

When an ELF program is execed by the kernel, it maps the executable file into memory.  It then looks in a special section for the "ELF loader", which, under Linux is (e.g.) `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.  The kernel maps the loader into the application memory and turns control of the program over to the loader.  The loader, in turn, resolves references to, and loads, the shared libraries the program needs, and then transfers control to the program's *start* function.

The `ldd` program will print out the shared libraries that a given program uses.  But, it doesn't actually do that itself.  It sets an env variable, then execs the target program.  The ELF loader sees this variable, and instead of executing the program, it merely loads it, printing the names of the shared libraries.  The ELF loader has many env vars that can affect its operation (e.g. see `man ld.so`).

Another library that uses the environment is `glibc`.  When `glibc` encounters a fatal error, such as double freeing a pointer, or heap corruption, it will print an error message.  Normally, `glibc` will output this to `/dev/tty`.  Sometimes, that's not desirable and we'd rather the error message go to `stderr` [where we've opened an error log file].  To get `glibc` to honor our wishes, we set the env var `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_` to `1` before we invoke the program.

---

This config stuff *could* be handled by a WinX registry-like interface and the data could reside in per-process kernel memory.  But, that's cumbersome for the kernel *and* the program.  The kernel doesn't want to carry this variable sized information in [precious] kernel address space.  An application doesn't want the overhead of using syscalls to get at it.

Most C programmers write their `main` function as `int main(int argc,char **argv)` but with what gets actually passed it could [more properly] be written as `int main(int argc,char **argv,char **envp)`.  The `envp` actually points to a definition:

```
char *environ[] = {
    "DISPLAY=:0",
    "PATH=/usr/bin:/bin",
    ...
    NULL
};
```

The libc functions `getenv`, `setenv`, `putenv` operate on the global.  But, when passing the pointer to `execvpe` you can specify a *different* env array altogether, filled with whatever you want.  So, you can manipulate the array [and, hence, the environment] directly.

---

*Historical footnote:*  environment variables aren't specific to Linux.  They weren't *added*--they have always been there [in Linux].  And, the environment has been part of just about *any* unix-like system, unchanged(!), since the earliest incarnations, just like `argc/argv`.  This goes back to [at least] Bell Labs' Unix V7 [and probably earlier].

Answer (score 0):

Variables are used for writing scripts and program management. For example, you can write a script greeting and indicate in it the variable $ USER, and it will display the name of the current user. Programs can access variables, and variables can be used in their work. For example, the programs running in the GUI on Linux, you can specify the X server, with which they will display their data.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables is really helpful for running programs on Linux. We usually need to read some system configurations in our program and environment variable is a good place to allow us to access these configurations.